# Exchange office 365 transport rules to block spam when FROM doesn't match smtp.mailfrom or return path

Tags: exchange, spam, microsoft-office-365, spam-filter

I'm sure this type of question has been answered already so I apologize in advance, but I can't seem to find anything. I have spf, dkim, dmarc all setup so I'm not worried about outgoing spam, but I have incoming spam coming through that's clearly spam when looking at the headers. \

Are there good transport rules to block when authentication fails, the smtp.mailfrom and from are different, and the to field is not the recipient? Also the subject and the from is getting encoded. Which might be how it's getting past basic spam filtering.

This seems like it should be easy, but I can't find anything...

```
From: =?utf-8?Q?=C6=8Aropbox?= <shared@onlineconnect.dpbox.com> 
Return Path: mjw@nutra-balance-products.com
Message ID: <1518007996.63064545@webmail.emailsrvr.com>
To: <me@dropbox.com>
Authentication-Results: spf=none (sender IP is 173.203.187.93) smtp.mailfrom=nutra-balance-products.com; mysitehere.com; dkim=none (message not signed) header.d=none;mysitehere.com; dmarc=none action=none header.from=onlineconnect.dpbox.com;
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?New_document_shared_-_=28investment-2018-en.pdf=29?= which decodes to New document shared - (investment-2018-en.pdf)
```

Answer (score 2):

The mismatch between `Return-Path` (envelope sender) and `From:` doesn't necessarily indicate spam and shouldn't be used as an explicit rule for blocking any messages.

For example we could have a situation where a mailing list forwards message for its subscribers. The mailing list can't change the behavior of SPF for the original sender and it should not modify the `From:` header specifying ([RFC 4021, 2.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4021#section-2.1.2)) the author(s) of the message. Therefore, it must change the envelope sender in order to pass the SPF test on the recipient side.

```
Return-Path: <postlist@example.net>
Received-SPF: Pass (mailfrom) identity=mailfrom; client-ip=198.51.100.30; 
    helo=mail.example.net; envelope-from=postlist@example.net; receiver=<UNKNOWN> 
To: <postlist@example.net>
From: "Original Sender" <user@example.com>
```

On the other hand, Office 365 mail flow rules aren't designed for doing such comparisons; you can for example compare senders with their location (inside / ouside tenant) or bypass filtering for trusted external servers. These are for addressing more specific problems, where heuristics fail.

If you think you only receive legitimate mails from senders that have SPF/DKIM/DMARC set, you could e.g. add a rule that alters *Spam Confidence Level* (SCL) based on `Authentication-Results` containing `spf=none` and `dkim=none`. Depending on your situation it may cause false positives.

Comment: While this answer is technically correct, there are already a lot of email systems blocking a ``From`` domain that doesn't match the envelope domain, and this is a vulnerable spot for businesses who are often the target of phishing that appears to come from people they know.  It would be nice if the answer here included "but here's how to do it anyway"